# Implementing section indexer in list view android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I want to add section headers in the list view in android like the attached image. Can some one help me with the code. I don't want to implement the side section indexer like in contacts.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KaTB.jpg)

This is the custim list adapter that I have created-

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity mContext;
    private List<String> mList;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = null;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> list){
        mContext = context;
        mList = list;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return mList.get(pos);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ListViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.players_name_with_options, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ListViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Setting the name of the player on the text view
        viewHolder.textView.setText(mList.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }


    // Class that contains the views as the variables
    private class ListViewHolder {

        TextView textView;

        // Constructor of the class
        public ListViewHolder(View item) {

            // Initialising the text view and the spinner
            textView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.list_textView);
        }
     }
}
```

I am initializing this `ArrayAdapter` and then adding the names of the players. I want that when ever the name is added then the section header be created and the player's name should be set below the header like the image that I had attached.

Comment: can you share what do you tried so far ?

Comment: I have edited the post. Please see to it

Comment: Create 2 different views for your items and item header. Then use `getItemViewType (int position)` method to set indexer or item while inflating a view and bind data accordingly in `getView()` method.

Comment: Can you please post come code. It would be really appreciated

Comment: This link was helpful in my case. Thank you all.             http://codetheory.in/android-dividing-listview-sections-group-headers/#comment-1910517

Answer (score 0):

There are many library available for this. Hope the below link will help you to figure out, what you need.

1. [pinned-section-listview](https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview)
2. [Example 1](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/02/24/listview-with-sections-in-android/)
3. [Example 2](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html)

Comment: Not working in my case. According to this when ever I add a player then it creates a new header for it. The players whose name start from the same alphabet should be under one header.

Comment: @Ahmad:: which means all players start with A has to be under A Section right?

Comment: Yes. This is what I need. Can you provide me with any code? Thanks

Comment: @Ahmad: Then you can proceed with example 1 link.. which is same as you need.